# Using list in parameter to create radiobuttons in GUI

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I used a list as a parameter for the GUI window, and each individual item in the list is supposed to be created as a radio button in the GUI window. Currently, I used a for loop to generate different values for each radio button and another for loop to generate different columns. However, I am only able to create a radio button for the last item in the list.

This is what I currently have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

class ExpenditureGUI:

def __init__(self, listOfCategories):
    self._listOfCategories = listOfCategories
    self._tk = Tk()
    self._tk.title('Expenditure Tracker')     
    self._tk.geometry('500x200')        
    self._tk.resizable(False,False)
    self.initWidgits()
    self._tk.mainloop()


@property    
def listOfCategories(self):
    return self._listOfCategories
@listOfCategories.setter
def listOfCategories(self, newValue):
    self._listOfCategories = newValue

def initWidgits(self):
    #flow layout
    topF = Frame(self._tk)
    self._lblAmount = Label(topF, text = 'Amount: ')      
    self._txtAmount = Entry(topF, width=30)


    rbtnF = Frame(topF)
    self._rbtnVar = IntVar()  
    self._rbtnVar.set(0)  
    self._lblExpenditure = Label(topF, text = 'Type of Expenditure: ')

    n = 0
    for type in self._listOfCategories:
        self._rbtntype = Radiobutton(rbtnF, text = f'{type}', value = n, variable = self._rbtnVar)


    self._lblExpenditure.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)

    n = 0
    for type in self._listOfCategories:
        self._rbtntype.grid(row = 0, column = n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not an expert in the GUI library, but this looks pretty suspect:

```
for type in self._listOfCategories:
        self._rbtntype = Radiobutton(rbtnF, text = f'{type}', value = n, variable = self._rbtnVar)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After this loop ends, the `self._rbtntype` variable will contain text referring to only the *last* element in the list of categories (i.e. the loop variable `type`).

You may want to construct a new `Radiobutton` in the final loop in your code sample.  Maybe something like this would work.  It probably needs to update `n` in each loop iteration.

```
for type in self._listOfCategories:
    rbtntype = Radiobutton(rbtnF, text = f'{type}', value = n, variable = self._rbtnVar)
    rbtntype.grid(row = 0, column = n)
```

Comment: Resolved! I realised the first loop did not create any radiobutton, thanks!